# How to create a pop up menu in Android

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

i tried the following code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;

public class Custom_dialogActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
String test[] = {"Security","Data Backup","Missing Device"};
ListAdapter adapter;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle("My Title");
    builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    builder.setItems(test, new OnClickListener() {  
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("onClick " + which);

        }
    });
    builder.setAdapter(adapter, new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("DialogInterface : " + which);
        }
    });
    EditText ed = new EditText(this);
    builder.setView(ed);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                            {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                             }
                       });
                builder.setNegativeButton("No",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which)
                            {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });

                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
          }
}
```

**but it looks like but i tried to set color and icon but failed to setIcon and Color Green on Top of Dialog box solve my problem and i didint created any xml and didnt made any changes **

[image]

but i want like

[image]

Comment: HINT: `Activity` with a `Dialog` theme.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this by using **AlertDialog.Builder**, but instead of using standard dialog, you need to *inflate* your own xml to override the view.

**update**

or create an activity with dialog style:

your custom **style**:

```
<style name="styleActivityDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
 <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
 <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
 <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
 <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
 <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@android:color/transparent</item>
 <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
 <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>

 <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bg_activity_dialog</item>
</style>
```

drawable **bg_activity_dialog**:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

      <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#C0C0C0" />
      <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
      <corners android:radius="5dp" />
      <padding android:top="5dp" android:bottom="5dp" android:left="5dp" 
         android:right="5dp"/>
    </shape>
```

your activity in **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityDialog"
     android:theme="@style/styleActivityDialog">
</activity>
```

now create any layout for your activity **ActivityDialog** and it should appear as a dialog window

Comment: hey if u know this than can you provide me link because using inflate i dont know how can i do it

Comment: read this blog http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-display-custom-dialog-your-android-application

Comment: but on Top how can i set Green color ?

Comment: it showing error on style.xml on this line <style name="myTheme.DialogBoxActivity">

Comment: also in manifest on this line android:theme="@style/myTheme.DialogBoxActivity"

Comment: `Clean` your project first and then build.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8059/discussion-between-rstar-and-waqas)

Comment: Why am I getting a cannot resolve symbol ".ActivityDialog" but the app runs fine and the dialog shows as inspected?

Answer (score 2):

You could create an Activity with the layout you desire and add the following theme to the Activity's tag in the AndroidManifest.xml to simulate a dialog look.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

If that is not enough, you can use inheritance and modify this specific theme to use a translucent, non-dim background.

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
     <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
     <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
     <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

Comment: dude it is just showing same dialog without background means on Wallpaper it shows dialog on Title side it showing down arrow

Comment: setting Theme.Dialog would still leave a dark color gutter at top and bottom of window.

Answer (score 2):

You can use AlertDialog or custom dialog.
I've discussed about this in my personal blog.You can just visit my humble blog if you desire.. 
http://androiddesk.wordpress.com/tag/dialog-in-android/page/2/